# angle() of a real number

Tags: matlab, angle, complex-numbers, phase

I'm a bit confused about the angle() function in Matlab, in particular when applied to an array of real numbers.

The angle() function should give me the phase of a complex number. Example: y = a + bi, ==> phase = arctan(b/a). Indeed, the following works:

```
for t=1:1000
    comp(t) = exp(1i*(t/10));
end

phase_good_comp1 = unwrap(angle(comp)); %this gives me the right answer
b = imag(comp);
a = real(comp);
phase_good_comp2 = atan(b./a); %this gives me the right answer too, but 
wrapped (not sure if there is a way to unwrap this, but unwrap() does not 
work)

figure(1)
plot(phase_good_comp1)
hold on
plot(phase_good_comp2,'--r')
legend('good phase1', 'good phase2')
title('complex number')
```

Here's the plot for the complex numbers --

[image]

Note that I can use either the angle() function, or the explicit definition of phase, as I have shown above. Both yield good results (I can't unwrap the latter, but that's not my issue).

Now if I apply the same logic to an array of real numbers, I should get a constant phase everywhere, since no imaginary part exists, so arctan(b/a) = arctan(0) = 0. This works if I use the explicit definition of phase, but I get a weird result if I use angle():

```
for t=1:1000
    ree(t) = cos((t/10));
end

phase_bad_re = unwrap(angle(ree)); %this gives me an unreasonable (?) answer
b = imag(ree);
a = real(ree);
phase_good_re = atan(b./a); %this gives me the right answer

figure(1)
plot(phase_bad_re)
hold on
plot(phase_good_re,'--r')
legend('bad phase', 'good phase')
title('real number')
```

Here's the plot for the real numbers --

[image]

Why the oscillation when I use angle()???

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the other conventional atan definition, implemented as `atan2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Matlab documentation tells you how to compute this:

> The angle function can be expressed as `angle(z) = imag(log(z)) = atan2(imag(z),real(z))`.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html

Note that they define it with `atan2` instead of `atan`.

Now your data is in the range of cosine, which includes both positive and negative numbers.  The angle on the positive numbers should be 0 and the angle on the negative numbers should be an odd-integer multiple of pi in general.  Using the specific definition that they've chosen to get a unique answer, it is pi.  That's what you got. (Actually, for the positive numbers, any even-integer multiple of pi will do, but 0 is the "natural" choice and the one that you get from `atan2`.)

If you're not clear why the negative numbers don't have angle = 0, plot it out in the complex plane *and keep in mind that the radial part of the complex number is positive by definition*. That is `z = r * exp(i*theta)` for *positive* `r` and `theta` given by this angle you're computing.

Comment: " ... the radial part of the complex number is positive by definition" clears up everything for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since sign of cosine function is periodically changed, angle() is also oscillated.

Please, try this.

```
a=angle(1);
b=angle(-1);
```

Phase of 1+i*0 is 0, while phase of -1+i*0 is 3.14.

But, in case of atan, b/a is always 0, so that the result of atan() is all 0.